# WKWebview : Ignoring request to load this main resource because it is outside the sandbox

Tags: ios, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

In our app we are using readium library SDK to load epub file. WKWebview could not be load epub file because epub has been downloaded from server and saved in document path.

WKwebview has issue with accessing that file.

Note :- Same is working in simulator but not in the real device.

Below is the console log :

Received an unexpected URL from the web process: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C2D90ACC-D0C9-4D52-A4C8-B6EB7181DB9E/Documents/Books/81004325324010/C8FFB99F71D319A460F954F2C12EA296/content/2aabc318-3199-4275-aed2-e7fbf57d626e/OEBPS/Text/cover.htm'
2020-01-23 20:13:27.800321+0530 Papyrus[819:168410] [Process] 0x102130c18 - WebPageProxy::Ignoring request to load this main resource because it is outside the sandbox
2020-01-23 20:13:27.800395+0530 Papyrus[819:168410] [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1

[image: file path which is not loading]
[image: in simulator debugger screenshot]
[image: in device debugger screenshot]

Comment: did you found any solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue, maybe a bug of WKWebView but the below steps are working for me.

[1] Get access,
Call ***`loadFileURL`*** function with base path URL where require access.
`open func loadFileURL(_ URL: URL, allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: URL) -> WKNavigation?`

[2] Load your HTML content,
Call ***`loadHTMLString`*** function after *`loadFileURL`* function with same base path URL to load content.
`open func loadHTMLString(_ string: String, baseURL: URL?) -> WKNavigation?`